# PhantomJS setting cookies as Read and Write

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

I am trying to login to a website with phantomJS by session AUTH cookie, I finished the code for it and everything is working perfect, the problem is the website have like another login system inside with the same cookie, once accessed the other page cookie will update the security auth token, so when I add the First cookie to phantom I see that it is set to read Only because i cant access what is inside the second login system as Website is trying to update the Cookie that I manually added but unfortunately it fails because the cookie is Set to read Only.

code I am using :

```
phantom.addCookie({
    'name':     'some name here',   /* required property */
    'value':    'some hash here',
    'domain':   'ea.some domain here.com',           /* required property */
    'path':     '/',
    'httponly': false,
    'secure':   false,
    'expires':  (new Date()).getTime() + (10000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 10 hour */
});
```

I tried to delete the session cookie before my script auto access the page that needs second Auth but it just log me out because i need to have my old Session auth so it can be updated with the new session authhash.

any ideas how to make manually added cookies to be updated once requested from server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

It appears that server actually created a new cookie with the same name and new value. not by replacing it with the new value. I searched the web for any help regarding this matter but I failed, I fixed this problem by taking the value of the new cookie and saving it to a variable, then executing `phantom.clearcookies()` to remove all the cookie and adding the new cookie again with the new value that I stores, It was not clean but it did the trick.